# not able to install pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

The error that I am recieving while trying to install Pyinstaller is:

i tried t0 install pyinstaller from anaconda with poxy.
pip install --proxy=https://:8080 pyinstaller

```
Using cached pyinstaller-4.3.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\local_e55hnwm\Temp\1\pip-build-env-_ley58wf\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools
       cwd: None
  Complete output (7 lines):
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD43EFCA90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD41F50460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD43EC50D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD43EC52E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DD43EC5490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\local_e55hnwm\Temp\1\pip-build-env-_ley58wf\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please describe the steps you have followed, and aim to share question body in structured form. Do not share only error you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can install with command:
*conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller*